# BootstrapVue no reconoce estilos

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Estoy utilizando Vue y quiero trabajar los estilos con **BootstrapVue** ya agregue las librerías como lo indica la documentación (No trabajare con NPM) pero mi proyecto no reconoce ningún estilo.

Alguien sabe que mas debo añadir o como solucionar el problema?

Comment: ¿En que parte añadiste los estilos? supongo que vas a trabajar con cdn

Comment: Si es correcto agregue los CDN de css en el head y los script antes de finalizar el body como debe ser

Comment: ¿podrias mostrar la ruta y el archivo donde estas agregando el cdn?

Comment: Gracias Saul, ya pude solucionarlo y el problema que tuve era por el js